# Is there a cheap and easy way to check for potentially unsafe UV exposure?

Tags: gel-electrophoresis, experimental-design

My lab has an older large Fotodyne tabletop UV transilluminator for visualizing gels.  It has a UV blocking cover that hopefully reduces UV that passes through, but I've always been suspcious as to how effective it is.  Obviously this part can be replaced with a new one, but short of guessing on the recommended 50 hr lifetime, how would one know the level of UV passsing through?  I considered simply placing a gel on top, but that is far from quantitative.  I am really just curious if there is an easy to make and/or obtain sensor that could be used to know when UV expose could be considered dangerous.

Comment: Is there a more appropriate tag than DNA?

Comment: Agreed, I'm still below the threshold for creating tags.  Safety or visualization would have been remotely closer.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic in its present state.  It's more about safety procedures than the formulating or running of gels.

Comment: @jonsca safety procedures should surely be included within experimental design?

Comment: @bobtheowl2 sorry about that, didn't even consider your rep!

Comment: @RoryM This seems more of an laboratory equipment maintenance issue rather than something directly involved with the process of experimental biology.  Perhaps a meta post is in order.

Comment: @jonsca sure sounds like a plan =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instrument you are looking for is probably an [UV-meter](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=004738989115247203233:09r2ltc-nlc&ie=UTF-8&q=UV-meter).

Comment: That does seem obvious after looking at products available in a google search.  Maybe one the reusable ~6 level color changing sensors would be adequate or even one of the ~$30 handheld digital models. Spending several hundred dollars is out of the question though. I was just hoping someone would say, oh yea all labs in the world use this cheap x sensor to warn us of excessive exposure (analogous to radiation badges).

Comment: @bobtheowl2 I did try and find a radiation badge style dosimeter for you but it seems the only ones they have at present are for 24/7 exposure studies and tend to be quantitative rather than a qualitative red light approach